# Ruby psych - YAML coversion referencing another resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, aws-cloudformation, psych

I recently started to use ruby psych to generate yaml strings from hashes..

I have a concern however, in case I need to `!Ref` or `!GetAtt` for another resource, it would end up being wrapped in double quoted strings after the YAML. For example:

```
      {
        'FooPolicy' => {
          'Type' => 'AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy',
          'Properties' => {
            'Queues' => '!Ref FooQueue',
            'PolicyDocument' => {
              'Statement' => {
                'Action' => 'SQS:*',
                'Effect' => 'Allow',
                'Resource' => '!GetAtt FooQueue.Arn',
                'Principal' => {
                  'AWS' => '${AWS::AccountId}'
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

The output is

```
  FooPolicy:
    Type: AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy
    Properties:
      Queues: "!Ref FooQueue"
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          Action: SQS:*
          Effect: Allow
          Resource: "!GetAtt FooQueue.Arn"
          Principal:
            AWS: "${AWS::AccountId}"
```

which is throwing malform message in Cloudformation validation... Has anyone run into this issue?

Comment: It looks like JSON might be a better option in this case  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v1/api/AWS/CloudFormation/StackCollection.html#create-instance_method, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-getatt.html It would be just as easy to implement.

Comment: Face palm... You are right lol, I totally forgot Cloudformation support other templating besides YAML.